# Padding issue - form group within modal dialog

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form element within a modal dialog with 2 text fields and 2 buttons. However, I am having some padding issues with the form group element. When I inspect the CSS element using FireFox I see that the `form-group` element is compressed and not padded as it should be. I dont have this issue when I use form-group elements in a regular page. I woner if this has something to do with the modal dialog. Can someone please advise? Code is below and so is a screenshot

[image: Form-group padding is compressed in the modal dialog]

```
<form role="form" action="edit-user.settings.controller.php" method="post" id="edit-user-form">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="link-job-modal-label">Edit User</h4>
        </div> <!-- .modal-header -->

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="first-name" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />
                </div>
            </div> <!-- .form-group -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="last-name" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />
                </div>
            </div> <!-- .form-group -->
        </div> <!-- .modal-body -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id-"cancel-btn">
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-btn">
                Save
            </button>
        </div> <!-- .modal-footer -->
    </form> <!-- End of edit-user-form -->
```

Also - here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chicagosky/02g22qxk/5/) - to see the problem in the fiddle - expand, horizontally, the result frame and you will see the same issue occur. I am now wondering if this has something to do with the layouts in a modal that affects form-group elements

Comment: This is a CSS issue, but you've posted no CSS. :-/

Comment: I am not using any custom CSS - I am using the default twitter bootstrap CSS

Comment: Update: If I add form-horizontal class to the form element then it displays correctly - but that doesnt make sense to me. I am not creating a horizontal form..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">` that is wrapping around your label/input.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="first-name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name (first last)" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="email" name="email" placeholder="e-mail" />
</div>
```

Best practice is to not stray far from the [Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), there are great examples and you can follow those easily.

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/02g22qxk/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

That is because this rule in bootstrap CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4,
    .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8,
    .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

By floating it, you are removing the parent element of the input element from normal document flow, causing the former's parent, `.form-group`, to collapse. A possible solution is to apply a simple clearfix, where you declare `overflow: hidden` to `.form-group`, i.e.:

```
.form-group {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/02g22qxk/6/

Alternatively, unwrap your form inputs from the unnecessary div containing the `.col-` class.

Comment: Thank you - i would have accepted your answer as well if i could. But thanks again - much appreciated